# MSBuild.exe halting when building a project, but builds successfully after restarting Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, linker, cgal

I'm working on some computational geometry problems and trying to use CGAL libraries to do some of the heavy-lifting. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, and CGAL 4.9. However, when I try to build and run my project, something strange happens: the build process gets stuck after "generating code", so the output looks like:

```
1>  Generating code
1>  63 of 8736 functions ( 0.7%) were compiled, the rest were copied from previous compilation.
1>    0 functions were new in current compilation
1>    43 functions had inline decision re-evaluated but remain unchanged
1>  Finished generating code
```

VS shows that there is still something going on (it is responsive, so VS doesn't hang per se), and if I try to close VS it gives an error that `The build must be stopped before the solution can be closed.`. I even tried to wait for a few hours to see what happens, and the build didn't finish. So I just ended the process "MSBuild.exe" using task manager (which caused VS to give an error that the process was exited)

```
1>MSBUILD : error MSB4166: Child node "2" exited prematurely. Shutting down. Diagnostic information may be found in files in the temporary files directory named MSBuild_*.failure.txt.
1>A task was canceled.
1>A task was canceled.
```

(I couldn't find the `MSBuild_*.failure.txt` file mentioned in the error message) After that, I closed VS, re opened the project, and tried to re-build the project. This time, it was successful, and it was very fast, a few seconds or so.

The problem happens once in a while (after a few edits to code, and rebuilding a couple of times), and always ending the build process and restarting VS solves the issue. I haven't had this problem in any other projects of mine, that's why I have the CGAL tag here, but it might have nothing to do with CGAL.

I wonder if anyone else has encountered this problem, and if there is a solution to it. I don't think it matters, but here is a simple program that has this problem:

```
#define CGAL_EIGEN3_ENABLED

#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h>
#include <CGAL/boost/graph/graph_traits_Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/boost/graph/properties_Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/extract_mean_curvature_flow_skeleton.h>
#include <CGAL/boost/graph/split_graph_into_polylines.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>                        Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_3                                       Point;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel>                            Polyhedron;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Polyhedron>::vertex_descriptor    vertex_descriptor;
typedef CGAL::Mean_curvature_flow_skeletonization<Polyhedron> Skeletonization;
typedef Skeletonization::Skeleton                             Skeleton;
typedef Skeleton::vertex_descriptor                           Skeleton_vertex;
typedef Skeleton::edge_descriptor                             Skeleton_edge;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream input((argc>1) ? argv[1] : "data/armadillo.off");
    Polyhedron tmesh;
    input >> tmesh;
    Skeleton skeleton;
    CGAL::extract_mean_curvature_flow_skeleton(tmesh, skeleton);
    std::ofstream output("skeleton.ply");
    output << "ply\n";
    output << "format ascii 1.0\n";
    output << "element vertex " << boost::num_vertices(skeleton) << "\n";
    output << "property float x\n";
    output << "property float y\n";
    output << "property float z\n";
    output << "end_header\n";
    BOOST_FOREACH(Skeleton_vertex v, vertices(skeleton))
        output << skeleton[v].point << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typical anti-malware signature, add an exclusion for your project directories.  If it is Avast then plan to get rid of it asap.

Comment: I see. Don't have Avast, but based on your comment, it can be either McAfee anti-virus or Avecto Defendpoint. Have to see if I can add exceptions to these and test if it solves the issue. Thanks :-)